# Title: Assertion Error - Missing Buffer Argument in Function vertexLineOnly_flat (Index 14)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm facing an issue in Swift, and I need help understanding and resolving a failed assertion. The error message I'm encountering is:

> **failed assertion `Function vertexLineOnly_flat does not have a buffer argument with buffer index 14'**

Thanks in advance.